# summarizing a text file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tab separated file like the small example and trying to make a new text file from that.

small example:

```
x   y1  y2  y3
a1  1   5   4
a2  3   6   9
a3  7   8   5
```

in the output file I would have 2 columns. the 1st column contains the headers of input file (from the 2nd column to the end) and they are repeated n times (n = number of rows in the input file). the 2nd column in the output file is the entire column (except header) after each other meaning the 3rd column is under 2nd column and the 4th column is under the 3rd column and they are all in front of their header (input file headers)

expected output:

```
YY  XX
y1  1
y1  3
y1  7
y2  5
y2  6
y2  8
y3  4
y3  9
y3  5
```

I made the following function in python3 but it does not return the expected output. do you know how to fix it?

```
def summ(infile, outfile):
    with open(infile, 'r') as f:
        res = {}
        line = f.split()
        res.keys = line[1]
        res.values = line[2:]
        of = open(outfile, "w")
        for k, v in res.items():
            of.write(str(k) + '\t'+ str(v) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pandas` and `numpy` you could rewrite as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def summ(infile, outfile):
    df = pd.read_csv(infile, index_col=0, delimiter="\t")
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([df[col].values for col in df.columns]), index=np.repeat(df.index.values, df.shape[0]), columns=['YY'])
    df2.index.names = ['XX']
    df2.to_csv(outfile, sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

First i would use pandas. Cause it does the parsing for you and give you great way to work with your data.

```
import pandas as pd
#Read your file, i suppose in fileName
dataFile = pd.read_csv(fileName,sep=" ")
#Now we do what is asked by concatenating each columbine after the other
dfOutput=pd.DataFrame()
tmpDict={}
tmpDict["XX"]=[]
tmpDict["YY"]=[]
for col in dataFile.columns:
    tmpDict["YY"]=[col]*len(dataFile)
    tmpDict["XX"]=dataFile[col]
    dfOutput=pd.concat([dfOutput,pd.DataFrame(tmpDict)])
dfOutput.to_csv(output,sep=" ",index=False)
```

I think it can be optimized :D. If you really need a way to do it without pandas, tell me.

Comment: Thanks. yes I actually need to that in a regular way not pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write sufficient code to solve this problem.  If you're not interested in using libraries like *csv* and *pandas* that would help you with tabular data, you could expand your current code to solve the problem:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def summ(infile, outfile):
    res = defaultdict(list)

    with open(infile) as inf:
        _, *keys = inf.readline().split()

        for line in inf:
            for i, value in enumerate(line.split()[1:]):
                res[keys[i]].append(value)

    with open(outfile, 'w') as outf:
        outf.write("YY\tXX\n")

        for key, values in res.items():
            for value in values:
                outf.write(key + "\t" + value + "\n")
```